# I am trying to pass some strings trough espeak and it reads them but I get "segmentation fault"

Tags: c++, string, input, segmentation-fault, espeak

This is my code. I want to get 5 strings from the user and espeak reads each of them when user interred it. But I get `segmentation fault(core dumped)` message.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <espeak/speak_lib.h>

int test()
{

espeak_POSITION_TYPE position_type;
espeak_AUDIO_OUTPUT output;
char *path=NULL;
int Buflength = 500, Options=0;
void* user_data;
t_espeak_callback *SynthCallback;
espeak_PARAMETER Parm;



char Voice[] = {"English"};

int i=0;
char text[1000];
unsigned int Size,position=0, end_position=0, flags=espeakCHARS_AUTO, *unique_identifier;


    output = AUDIO_OUTPUT_PLAYBACK;

    espeak_Initialize(output, Buflength, path, Options ); 
    espeak_SetVoiceByName(Voice);
    const char *langNativeString = "en_US";
    espeak_VOICE voice={0};

        voice.languages = langNativeString;
        voice.name = "US";
        voice.variant = 2;
        voice.gender = 1;
       Size = strlen(text)+1;    


for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{

scanf("%s ", &text);

printf("%s", text);

    espeak_Synth( text, Size, position, position_type, end_position, flags,
    unique_identifier, user_data );
    espeak_Synchronize( );
fflush(stdout);

}

return 0;
}






int main(int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{
    test();

    return 0;
}
```

I tried some modification but none of them worked. I want the program works like this:

> User input: hi
>
> espeak says: hi
>
> user input: one
>
> espeak says: one
>
> (for 5
>   inputs)

But when I try to interring more than 4 characters as input,it gives `segmentation fault` error!

Comment: Where does the segfault occur?

Comment: @lxop: When I try to interring more than 4 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main issues are:

1. you use `strlen` on an uninitialized array of chars;
2. the `unique_identifier` argument of `espeak_Synth` must be `NULL` or point to an unsigned int (see the [source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/espeak/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/speak_lib.h#l322)) while now it is an unsigned pointer to random memory.

Move `strlen` after `scanf`, use `NULL` instead of `unique_identifier` and your code will suddenly work (kind of).

There are many other issues though: useless variables, uninitialized variables, no input sanitization and more. IMO a better approach would be to throw away the `test` function and rewrite it from scratch properly.

### Addendum

This is how I'd rewrite the above code. It is still suboptimal (no input sanitization, no error checking) but IMO it is **much** cleaner.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <espeak/speak_lib.h>

static void say(const char *text)
{
    static int initialized = 0;
    if (! initialized) {
        espeak_Initialize(AUDIO_OUTPUT_PLAYBACK, 0, NULL, 0);
        espeak_SetVoiceByName("en");
        initialized = 1;
    }
    espeak_Synth(text, strlen(text)+1,
                 0, POS_CHARACTER, 0,
                 espeakCHARS_UTF8, NULL, NULL);
    espeak_Synchronize();
}

int main()
{
    char text[1000];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        scanf("%s", text);
        say(text);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: May you tell me which lines are useless?

Comment: Basically all the lines with those pesky variables. I added a code example for reference.